# Windows 10: set default network location to Public

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, network-shares, wifi-configuration

Windows 10 prompts you to enable/disable LAN sharing every time you connect to a new wifi network. Is there a way to make it stop asking and defaults to "disable" or "public network"?